# Script to change value of DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, batch-file

I have a chrome extension I would like to share with some colleagues. There's no type of login available yet but I would like each user to have the tool in their name.

Prior to them installing the extension I would like to have a script that will change the hard coded values to their name and location.

```
1) Share the tool
2) Click BAT/Script file of similar
3) Script executes and a form asks for 'User' / 'Location'
4) Hard coded values in index.html are changed
5) Install tool, HTML now is in their name
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="xuser"><h4>John Smith</h4>      <!-- Set User Name --></div>
<div class="xloc"><h4>UK Team</h4>      <!-- Set Location --></div>
```

is there any better solution?

Comment: **2) Click BAT/Script file of similar**    imagine the security :))

Comment: Security? Not an issue, its an internal application with no valued data. Instead of asking people to edit the HTML prior to installing, I would like to release with a script to do this for them

Comment: why do you need the username and the location, what use do you have for them?

Comment: I log certain things using the tool, I would like to know under which user certain things were logged

Comment: you will need a server to process the form and generate the html

Comment: You can read and write files with javascript if it's just a local file I'd save settings as a json file and read that file to fill in details.